# Permission denied to delete project Google Cloud, how to proceed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am having a very tinted design on the dashboard. I'm trying to delete but I get the message "does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it." . All right, but. How can I not have permission because I am the only user to use the service. I need to delete but I am facing this difficulty.

I am the only user of the service.
No one else uses the platform

[Project permissions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osNwU.jpg)

[Role:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x15TT.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Despite this is a pretty old topic, but did you find the solution? I have the same issue and can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

I faced same issue and finally figured this out. I hope other people can benefit from this.

If your project is under "No Organization", you can simply go to IAM, make sure you are owner, then go to project, delete/shutdown buttons will be enabled, you can delete the project.

However if you have created an organization, even if you are owner/admin of a project, you do not have delete permission. First you need to go to admin settings page and grant yourself "project deleter" role, then you will be able to shutdown/delete a project.

To give yourself "project deleter" role, go to IAM -> settings, Open dropdown at the top where you can select a project, click on all, click on your oganization name. Here you will see your email as "Organization Administrator". Edit this and add "Project Deleter".

Did this help anyone?

Comment: It helped me immensely. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Only project owners can shut down the project, so make sure you are logged in as an account with the Project Owner permission before you try to delete the project. You must first disable billing before deleting any project by shutting down the project. If you are as an owner of project make sure that your log in with the right email.

Also, shutting down a project does not delete the project immediately. It only requests deletion of the project. The project owner will receive an email notification that the project has been marked for deletion
To shut down a project using the GCP Console:

> 1) Open the [Setting page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?_ga=2.6110768.-203031571.1517337342) (found under IAM & admin) in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
>   2) Click Select a project.
>   3) Select a project you wish to delete, and click Open.
>   4) Click Shut down. Then click DELETE PROJECT. A confirmation screen describing what will happen appears.
>   5) Now enter the Project ID, then click Shut down.

For more information about shutting down/deleting the project please have a look at these following links with:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_deleting_projects

https://support.google.com/cloud#topic=6158848

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.

I know all the steps to delete a project, even deleted others.
I am the sole owner and user of all cloud services, there is no one else interacting with this account, just me.

The problem starts with this project in question in 2 years using Google Cloud I have never seen a project where I am not allowed to delete. Very strange even seems that it was created by the platform itself.

Answer (score 0):

Open IAM and check for project permissions. check members and their roles. Check who is the owner of the project. what is your role? If you are the owner under roles and still not able to delete the project,  then raise an issue in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues.

Comment: I am the only user of the platform and its services. No one else has access to or participates in the projects. I do not understand how this project was created. I as the sole owner can not delete.
I'll raise the problem on the link that you sent me.  Thank you.